# Css How to make elements after span appear on different line while shrinking

Tags: html, css

Consider this code:

```
<h2 class="section-title">what <span>Client Say?</span></h2>
```

When I shrink it get shown like this:

[image]

I want to make it like this(Ignore the underline)

[image]

What's the simplest way of achieving this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is so basic at least try to research the answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS rule for your span:

```
h2.section-title > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with a `<br>` tag, or put this code in the p selector:

```
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
p{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
span{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>What <br><span>Client say?</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a sans-serif font, upper case inside the span.
Note that the `span` might better be a `div` but you already provided the markup so we force it here to `block` display effectively the same thing.

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

h2.section-title>span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:1.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section-title">what <span>Client Say?</span></h2>
```